# Insert values in a table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to write a Stored Procedure. 
I have a table with some data now I need to insert relevant data into another table according to some condition

Example:

```
Table 1

Name     Class Math Physics English
Alok     V     60   50      45
Bobby    V     78   87      86
Chandini VI    56   76      56
Dolly    VII   87   56      66
```

Based on this condition

```
Insert Values into Table2 
If class =V  
(Table2.Physics=Select sum(Table1.Physics) from Table1 where Class like ‘V’
 Table2.Maths=0 and table2.English=0)

If class =VI  
(Table2.Maths=Select sum(Table1.Maths) from Table1 where Class like ‘VI’
 Table2.Physics=0 and table2.English=0)

If class =VI  
(Table2.English =Select sum(Table1.English) from Table1 where Class like ‘VII’
 Table2.Physics=0 and table2.Maths =0)
]
```

```
Table 2

Class Math Physics English
V     0    137     0
VI    56   0       0
VII   0    0       66
```

Kindly Help me out

Comment: see if this helps http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT
INTO    table2
SELECT  class,
        SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'V' THEN Physics ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'VI' THEN Math ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'VII' THEN English ELSE 0 END)
FROM    table1
GROUP BY
        class
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a stored procedure or even another table?

A **view** servers you better as it can never go off sync with the real data. (There is no real performance issue either.)

```
CREATE VIEW table2 AS
SELECT class,
       SUM(CASE WHEN table1.class = 'V' THEN table1.physics ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN table1.class = 'VI' THEN table1.math ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN table1.class = 'VII' THEN table1.english ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1
GROUP BY class
```

Comment: This is the same as @Quassnoi 's solution but with a view.